# Delete Pivot Calculated Fields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I want to delete a calculated field in a Pivot table.
I know I can't do this before setting the same calculated field as visible = false.
So I set the calculated field in object as not visible.

I tried two identical lines of code (below).
The first lines contains two variables set with the same values that you can find in the second line.

```
pt = "Tabella pivot3"
CampoCalcolatoToDelete = "w 49 - 06/12 CC"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt).CalculatedFields(CampoCalcolatoToDelete).Delete
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella pivot3").CalculatedFields("w 49 - 06/12 CC").Delete
```

The second line is working fine.
The first one (with variables) it is not working.

Can anyone suggest why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your variables in your code:

```
Dim pt, CampoCalcolatoToDelete as String

pt = "Tabella pivot3"
CampoCalcolatoToDelete = "w 49 - 06/12 CC"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt).CalculatedFields(CampoCalcolatoToDelete).Delete
```

Are there any errors given when you attempt to run the line from your code that uses the variables?

Comment: Hi Scott, you had a clue. pt was declared as Pivot Table. I've created a new variable (declared as String): `ptString = pt`. Now it's working fine. Thanks!